# How to pass on a form through Ajax, and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to this, I just want it to work with simple code then i'll add onto it. But it's not working in the sense that i don't get an echo. I just want to submit a form and have it not refresh the page.

here is my form

```
<form >
 <input type="text" id="name" >
 <input type="submit" value="s"  onclick="return chl()" >
</form>
```

**here is my js**

```
<script>
function chl(){

  var name= document.getElementByID('name').value;
  var dataString='name' + name; 

  $.ajax({
     type:"post",
     url:"hi.php",
     data:dataString,
     cache:false,
     success: function(html){
       alert ("success"); 
     }
   });
   return false;
}
</script>
```

and here is my php

```
<?php

$name=$_POST ['name'];
echo "response".$name; 

?>
```

Comment: the js and html are in the same page

Answer (score 2):

The datastring should be formed like a querystring; you've missed the `=` between the key and the value:

```
var dataString = 'name=' + name;
```

That being said, you can improve your code. Firstly you should attach the event to the `submit` of the form, and use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the normal form submission. Also, you can use `serialize()` to generate an object containing the forms' values to pass across in the AJAX request. The response from your PHP code will be retuned in the parameter sent to the `success` handler, so you need to do something with it there. Lastly, you should attach your events in JS, not HTML attributes, for a better separation of concerns. Try this:

```
<form method="hi.php">
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="s" />
</form>
```

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
             alert(html); // = 'response: name = [VALUE]'
        }
    });
});
```

```php
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "response: name = ".$name;
```

Comment: You need to run PHP code on a server. To execute it locally you need to run an XAMP setup.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--form method="hi.php"--> <!-- Remove this from your code and method is post or get you can't use hi.php as method  -->
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" id="click" value="s" /> <!-- Give id to your button  -->
<!--/form-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> <!-- You need to use jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
$('#click').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    var name=$('#name').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'hi.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {name: name}
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert(data); // You can alert that data 
        console.log(data); //or you view this data on console  Ctrl+shift+I
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });

});

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
<!-- Your php page hi.php -->
<?php
echo $_POST['nmae'];
// or just say  hi
echo 'hi';

?>
```

Comment: can you please tell how to separate the files  ? 

I tried by starting the js file like
$('#click').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 1):

Form

```
<form name="test" id="test">
 <input type="text" id="name" >
 <input type="submit" value="s" >
</form>
```

Script

```
<script>
$("#test").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var name= document.getElementByID('name').value;

  $.ajax({
     type:"post",
     url:"hi.php",
     data:{"name":name},
     cache:false,
     success: function(html){
       alert (html); 
     }
   });
   return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with -

```
var dataString = $('form').serialize();
```

By this you can get rid of generating the `datastring` if you have a number of input fields.

Answer (score 0):

change ajax function like and send data as shown below and your php and js function must be in different pages

```
function chl(){
   var name= document.getElementByID('name').value;
   $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"hi.php",
      data:{name:name},
      success: function(html){
         alert ("success"); 
      } 
   });
   return false;
}
```

Comment: when i put the function in it's own page, i should remove the onclick attribute right?

Comment: nop !! but when u put js and php  both in a same page how could u make js function's call and get request

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="server.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="myName" >
    <input type="submit" value="s"  onclick="chl(); return false;" >
</form>

<script>
    function chl()
    {
        var nameElement = document.getElementById("myName");  
        //Creates formData object and sends it to PHP script
        var formData = new FormData();
            //name equals to input element name attribute value    
            formData.append(nameElement.name, nameElement.value);
         var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
             {
                 if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                 {
                     alert(xmlHttp.responseText);  
                 }
             }
             xmlHttp.open("POST", "server.php");
             xmlHttp.send(formData);

    }

</script>


<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo $name;
?>
```